# How do you fail a build based on the result of a single Findbugs detector?

Tags: java, ant, build-process, findbugs

If you are using [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/index.html) for compiled code inspection, is it possible to fail a build based on the result of a single detector or category of detectors?

For example, I would like to ensure that I don't have any null pointer-related detections (prefix of "NP" in [this list](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html)) of any priority.  Likewise, we really don't want to have any [wait not in loop](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#WA_NOT_IN_LOOP) situations.  That said, I don't necessarily want to fail a build based on internationalization detections as those aren't immediately critical to our application.

The desired end-state would be a process that we could tune for a variety of development phases ranging from the IDE level (Eclipse and Netbeans) to the release level (builds are generated using CruiseControl).

NOTE: I am aware that Eclipse and Netbeans both have similar detection methods built-in but this is a FindBugs specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [FindBugs Using the Ant Task section](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html#d0e1334):

> `includeFilter`
>
> Optional attribute. It specifies the filename of a filter specifying which bugs are reported. See [Chapter 8, Filter Files](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html).

From Chapter 8:

> However, a filter could also be used to select bug instances to specifically report:
>
> `$ findbugs -textui -include myIncludeFilter.xml myApp.jar`

and

> 1. Match certain tests from all classes by specifying their abbreviations.

```
 <Match>
     <Bug code="DE,UrF,SIC" />
 </Match></pre>
```

So I would assume something along the lines of:

```
<Match>
    <Bug code="Wa,NP" />
</Match>
```

In your include filter and

```
<findbugs includeFilter="path/to/includefilter.xml"...
```

Would be what you're looking for.

The `path/to /includeFilter` (or `excludeFilter`) could be a property that gets set based on the value of another property which could default to something like `dev` for regular builds, `test` for CI builds, and `deploy` for deployment builds and specify which specific warnings you want to see or don't want to see at each stage.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Does this just generate reports, or would it actually cause an Ant build to fail?